# javascript (addeventlistener) не работает в iOS

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование, github-pages, codepen

Я добавил свой код в [github](https://abdulazizs-hub.github.io/en) всё работал потом узнал что он не работает ниже iOS 13. Но в [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Abdulazis/full/NWbwGPV) он четко работает.
Вот отрывок кода:

index.html:

```
         <section class="group gmin_height group_pad">
            <figure class="group_logo"><img src="media/svg/IticketLogo.svg" alt="Group Logo" /></figure>
            <div class="toggle_cont" visible>
                <p class="group_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt eveniet quae repellat dolores animi amet nemo quis tempora vero dignissimos fugit doloribus debitis sunt quod consequatur, quasi maiores sit mollitia. Porro facilis maxime unde esse et, labore magnam aliquam aspernatur. </p>
                <div class="group_btn"><a href="#" onclick="return false" class="btn_text">Сайт в разработке</a>
                </div>
            </div><button class="btn_show" data-text-swap='Свернуть<i class="arrow up"></i>'>Узнать больше<i
                    class="arrow down"></i></button>
        </section>
```

script.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
const target = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text-swap]");
  let touchEvent = "ontouchstart" in window ? "touchstart" : "click";
  for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    target[i].addEventListener(touchEvent,function () {
        target[i].closest(".group") ?.querySelector(".toggle_cont").toggleAttribute("visible");
        if (target[i].getAttribute("data-text-swap") == target[i].innerHTML) {
          target[i].innerHTML = target[i].getAttribute("data-text-original");
          target[i].classList.remove("cgray");
        } else {
          target[i].setAttribute("data-text-original", target[i].innerHTML);
          target[i].innerHTML = target[i].getAttribute("data-text-swap");
          target[i].classList.add("cgray");
        }
      },true
    );
  }
}
```

Кстати, сайт должен быть открыт на устройстве iOS ниже 13 версии или тут => https://appetize.io/demo?device=iphone5s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=12.4

Пробовал поставить **cursor: pointer** не получилось. И по техзадание не надо исползовать ни какого библиотек, чисто JavaScript

Буду очень рад за любой ответ! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что iOS 12.5 не поддерживала мой код. Пришлось изменить `<button>` в `<checkbox>` и использовать `#checkbox: checked`. Остальной код в JavaScript работает. Спасибо за невнимательность! Я многому научился из этого

Comment: Привет! Добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://example.com)